# Oracle sub select query qith aggregation function

Tags: oracle, aggregate-functions, subquery

```
    ID  FirstName   LastName 
1   John        Smith    
2   Mike        Smith 
3   Ben         Bray 
4   John        Bray 
5   John        Smith 
6   Bill        Lynch 
7   Bill        Smith
```

Hi there. I'm trying to do a subselect query in oracle with MIN and MAX functions, but i can't seem to get on the right track. Any Help would be appreciated.

example: I'm looking in the table for Carl Brayland.
If he doesn't exist i want to get the first name before Carl Brayland which will give me ID 3 -> Ben Bray

example2: I'm looking in the table for Mike Mad
If he doesn't exist i want to get the first name before Mike Mad which will give me ID 6 -> Bill Lynch

Last name should be leading.

Answer (score 0):

use ROWNUM on the sorted set (here `:p_lastname := 'Mad'; :p_firstname := 'Mike';`):

```
SQL> WITH my_data AS (
  2     SELECT 1 ID, 'John' FirstName, 'Smith' LastName FROM DUAL
  3     UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Mike', 'Smith' FROM DUAL
  4     UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Ben' , 'Bray'  FROM DUAL
  5     UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'John', 'Bray'  FROM DUAL
  6     UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'John', 'Smith' FROM DUAL
  7     UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'Bill', 'Lynch' FROM DUAL
  8     UNION ALL SELECT 7, 'Bill', 'Smith' FROM DUAL
  9  )
 10  SELECT id, firstname, lastname
 11    FROM (SELECT id, firstname, lastname
 12             FROM my_data
 13            WHERE lastname <= :p_lastname
 14              AND (lastname < :p_lastname OR firstname <= :p_firstname)
 15            ORDER BY lastname DESC, firstname DESC)
 16   WHERE ROWNUM = 1;

        ID FIRSTNAME LASTNAME
---------- --------- --------
         6 Bill      Lynch
```

Comment: Hi Vincent, thanks for your reply. i'm gonna test this query right away!

Comment: Hi Vincent, It works like a charm. Even with 7 million records. Thanks again!